# how to correctly configure maxResultSize?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I cant find a way to set driver max results size. Below is my configuration.

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/usr/local/bin/postgresql-42.2.5.jar")
                               ,("spark.executor.instances", "4")
                               ,("spark.executor.cores", "4")
                               ,("spark.executor.memories", "10g")
                              ,("spark.driver.memory", "15g")
                               ,("spark.dirver.maxResultSize", "0")
                              ,("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled","true")
                               ,("spark.memory.offHeap.size","20g")])


sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.getConf().getAll()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

i get this error after joining 2 large tables and getting collect

```
'Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o292.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 101 tasks (1028.8 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (1024.0 MB)'
```

I have seen similar problems on stackoverflow advising to maxResultsize but I can;t figure out how to do that correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick. Also note that you have mis-spelled `("spark.executor.memories", "10g")`. The correct configuration is `'spark.executor.memory'`.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .master('yarn') # depends on the cluster manager of your choice
    .appName('StackOverflow')
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/usr/local/bin/postgresql-42.2.5.jar')
    .config('spark.executor.instances', 4)
    .config('spark.executor.cores', 4)
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '10g')
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '15g')
    .config('spark.memory.offHeap.enabled', True)
    .config('spark.memory.offHeap.size', '20g')
    .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '4096') 
)
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Alternatively, try this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
          .setMaster('yarn') \
          .setAppName('StackOverflow') \
          .set('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/usr/local/bin/postgresql-42.2.5.jar') \
          .set('spark.executor.instances', 4) \
          .set('spark.executor.cores', 4) \
          .set('spark.executor.memory', '10g') \
          .set('spark.driver.memory', '15g') \
          .set('spark.memory.offHeap.enabled', True) \
          .set('spark.memory.offHeap.size', '20g') \
          .set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '4096') 

spark_context = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful, I assigned all my variables wrongly :). Now i get this error:
'Builder' object has no attribute 'SparkContext'

Comment: @user1871528 I've edited my answer to include the required imports. Hope it helps.

Comment: The error is caused by "sc = spark.sparkContext" I get the following error: "'Builder' object has no attribute 'SparkContext'"

Comment: @user1871528 OK. Updated my answer. Let me know if the second approach has worked.

Comment: I spoke too soon, when I said it works the spark context works. I still get the same error "Total size of serialized results of 101 tasks (1031.4 MB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize " I am running it locally and not in Yarn does that make a difference?

Comment: @user1871528 What if you try to pass the configuration to `spark-submit`? i.e. `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=4096`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193944/discussion-between-user1871528-and-giorgos-myrianthous).

Comment: the post mispelled spark.driver.maxResultSize as spark.dirver.maxResultSize. This might have been a source of the confusion.

Comment: I still get the "'Builder' object has no attribute 'SparkContext'". @user1871528

Answer (score 0):

Old post but there was a typo in: "spark.dirver.maxResultSize". Should of course be "spark.driver.maxResultSize"